# Copying file to another directory does not work

Tags: c++

I got the following code from a website which copies a file to another, it compiles and run, but the content of the output file does not change.
Can somebody point out where is the problem?
Im using dev c++ IDE (**edit**: probably with mingw).

```
 #include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    CopyFile("C:\\Users\\KEVIN\\Documents\\c++\\t.txt","C:\\Users\\KEVIN\\Documents\\c++\\output.txt",false);
system("pause");
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I'd `#include <windows.h>`, delete your definition of `CopyFile`, and just call the [`CopyFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) that's built into Windows.

Comment: i did like this, but the content of output.txt does not change?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

This is not C++ question anymore. 
Windows protect special folders, like `C:`, `C:\windows` etc. You either need to run program as admin or just create a temp folder in `C:` to access it.

Below code has undefined behavior, it create fileSize/2 memory block but tried to read/write with fileSize, it's out of boundry.

```
short * buffer = new short[fileSize/2];
initialFile.read((char*)buffer, fileSize);
```

To fix:

```
short * buffer = new short[fileSize];
```

I'd like to take JerryCoffin's idea, just use windows CopyFile function instead.

Comment: i found out that i can not open the file tho

Comment: It's an array of shorts so it's the correct size if fileSize is even, but one byte short if odd

Comment: @keivn that's another issue but this piece of code also crashes

Comment: sizeof short is 2 isn't it? 2*filesize/2 is filesize if even, filesize-1 if odd.

Comment: did what you guys told me to, but i got this print out

Comment: cout<<"I couldn't open "<<outputFilePath<<" for copying!\n";

Comment: @TonyLee, if fileSize is 10 bytes, buffer has 5 bytes allocated then read(buffer,filesize) will try to write 10 bytes in. get it?

Comment: @keivn, make a temp folder under `C:`, then you can  write to it. windows protects some special folders

Comment: what if I want to access a directory that i want?

Comment: @billz How big is a short?  It's 2 bytes  5*2 gets you 10 bytes.  The code is still wrong, if fileSize is 11 bytes buffer has 10 bytes (5 shorts).

Comment: tried using a temp folder, but it just cant copy the content to another file?

Comment: @billz - if I new uint64_t - how many bytes does that allocate - 8.  If I new uint64_t[2], how many bytes does that allocate - 16 (2*8).  Where does the 8 come from?  The size of uint64_t.